# Problem with CKEDITOR (attachments PATH/URL) integrated in Django contact mail form

Tags: python, django, url, ckeditor, attachment

I integrated ckeditor in my contacts form-email following the instructions provided by the official documentation and it works correctly.

My problem is the following (both locally and in production): when I attach an image or an attachment (via ckeditor uploader) and send the email from the form, I receive an email in which the image is not visible and the attachment is not downloadable. By copying the link of the image or attachment, the path is shown and not the url .. I think this is the problem.

Don't know how to fix it? Anyone have any ideas?
Thank you in advance!!!

Below is the code I used:

**settings.py**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'appForum/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'appEventi/static')
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/django/static-serve"    

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media-serve')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'ckeditor_uploads'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"
CKEDITOR_BROWSE_SHOW_DIRS = True

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
'toolbar_custom': {
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'skin': 'moono-lisa',
        'width': 'auto',
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'],
            ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-',
                'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
            ['Link', 'Unlink'],
            ['RemoveFormat', 'Source',],
            {'name': 'insert', 'items': ['Image', 'Update', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar']},
            {'name': 'extra', 'items': ['CodeSnippet']},
        ],
    },
}
```

**models.py**

```
    from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

# Create your models here.
class Contacts(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, verbose_name=_("First Name"))
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30,verbose_name=_("Last Name"))
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 50,verbose_name=_("Email"))
    subject = models.CharField(max_length = 150,verbose_name=_("Subject"))
    message = RichTextUploadingField(config_name="toolbar_custom",blank=False, null=False,verbose_name=_("Message"))
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Contacts


class ContactsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contacts
        #fields = ["first_name","last_name","email","subject","message"]
        fields = '__all__'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
# ...
path('contacts_as', ContactsView, name='contact'),
# ...
# Third Party Apps
path(_('ckeditor/'), include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
# ...
```

]

**views.py**

```
def ContactsView(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    contacts_form = ContactsForm(request.POST)
    if contacts_form.is_valid():
        new_message = contacts_form.save()
        subject = "Message from madlyuk.it: " + contacts_form.cleaned_data['subject']
        body = {
            'first_name': contacts_form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
            'last_name': contacts_form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
            'email': contacts_form.cleaned_data['email'],
            'message': contacts_form.cleaned_data['message'],
        }
        message = "\n".join(body.values())
        try:
            msg = EmailMessage(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER])
            msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
            msg.send()
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return redirect("success")
else:
    contacts_form = ContactsForm()
context = {"form": contacts_form}
return render(request, "contacts.html", context)
```

**contacts.html template**

```
    <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        {{ form.media }}
        <br>
        <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="INVIA">
        </div>

    </form>
```

For greater clarity, I am also attaching the image of the email I receive:[Email Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un7U7.jpg)

Comment: Nobody has any idea why, both the images and the attachments show a PATH and not a URL and are therefore neither visible nor downloadable?

Comment: I try to better define the request:
- in the case of sending emails via the contact form, where I attach a file or upload an image, the relative path appears and not the complete url.
To give an example of uploading a file, I get in the mail:
/media/ckeditor_uploads/2021/03/24/23012021-aso-lezione-1_a111c2251facc33d076934832beac280_nPZnC4s.pdf
and not:
http://127.0.0.1:8000//media/ckeditor_uploads/2021/03/24/23012021-aso-lezione-1_a111c2251facc33d076934832beac280_nPZnC4s.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I still consider myself a Junior programmer in the python world, but I found a solution: I don't know if stylistically it's a good solution, but it solves the problem. I have tested it both locally and online and it works.

```
def replace_relatve_path_with_Absolute_url(request, message):
    search_pattern = settings.MEDIA_URL + settings.CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH
    replace_with = request.build_absolute_uri(search_pattern)
    if __name__ == "appContatti.views": # contact form mail App.views
        message = message.replace(search_pattern, replace_with)
        return message
```

I added the following method in the views.py of my contact form app.
This method converts the relative address of the uploaded attachments or images to an absolute url.
The method checks to be called only in the case of the contact form mail and to leave the behavior unchanged in the case of other views

In ContactsView (the contacts form mail views), i've change the body massage:

```
body = {
                'first_name': contacts_form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
                'last_name': contacts_form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
                'email': contacts_form.cleaned_data['email'],
                # 'message': contacts_form.cleaned_data['message'],
                'message': replace_relatve_path_with_Absolute_url(request, contacts_form.cleaned_data['message']),
            }
```